# How to convert '0.153318751780503D-06' value to float?

Tags: python

I got a '0.153318751780503D-06' string format number by ansys.
But, I want to convert this to float number.

What should i do at python?

Comment: What does D-06 stand for?

Comment: I think It seems like E. It means exponential. For example, 5E-02 = 0.05

Answer (score 1):

As you are getting a string, you can replace the `D` with an `E`;

```
n = '0.153318751780503D-06'

replace_n = float(n.replace('D', 'E'))
```

Comment: Thanks. Can i ask one more question? If the data is so large, then, Do i have to replace each value and reassign? Only This method is there?